# textBox1.Text.Insert(...) method doesn't work

Tags: c#, string, methods, insert

I'm facing this abnormal situation. The following code doesn't work properly:

```
        string temp = "heythere";
        Console.WriteLine(temp);
        temp.Insert(3, "hello");
        Console.WriteLine(temp);
```

Isn't it supposed to output like "heyhellothere" ? But it does "heyrehere" (no change).

Comment: Please, specify a language or framework you use next time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strings are immutable, they don't change in-place. Try:

```
string temp = "heythere";
Console.WriteLine(temp);
temp = temp.Insert(3, "hello");
Console.WriteLine(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, your can try this

```
string temp = "heythere";
Console.WriteLine(temp.Insert(3, "hello"));
```